# Fundo em JDesktopPane sem perder qualidade e expansível

Tags: java, swing, jdesktoppane

Tenho código para adicionar uma imagem de fundo em um `JDesktopPane`e ele funciona perfeitamente em telas widescreen 16:10. Porém, quando a tela é um pouco mais larga (16:9), ele não preenche o restante do fundo. Eu vi alguns outros jeitos possíveis de fazer, porém eles fazem a imagem perder muita qualidade, pois só esticam elas.

É possível fazer um meio termo ? algo que preencha **quando necessário**, e que não tenha perda tão significantes na imagem?

```
package novo;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TesteJDP extends JFrame {

    private static MeuJDesktopPane jdp = new MeuJDesktopPane();

    public TesteJDP() {
        getContentPane().add(jdp);
        setSize(500, 450);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TesteJDP teste = new TesteJDP();
        teste.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MeuJDesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

    private Image imagem;

    public MeuJDesktopPane() {
        try {
            imagem = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagens/fundo.png")).getImage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possivel ler a imagem !");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension dimension = this.getSize();
        int x = (int) (dimension.getWidth() - imagem.getWidth(this)) / 2;
        int y = (int) (dimension.getHeight() - imagem.getHeight(this)) / 2;
        g.drawImage(imagem, x, y, imagem.getWidth(this), imagem.getHeight(this), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: O meio termo você ja respondeu, fixar o tamanho da janela conforme a imagem ou colocar uma imagem maior.

Comment: @diegofm já experimentei colocar uma imagem bem grande, não sei o que acontece, ela não preenche tudo. Não tem como adicionar alguma dimensão ou algo pra força preencher ?

Comment: Qual as dimensões da imagem?

Comment: @diegofm 2.362 px X 1.570 px

Comment: Sua janela tem apenas (500, 450) de dimensao, como uma imagem 3x maior não preenche tudo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Obs.: A solução foi aplicada a um `JDesktopPane`, mas como o método `paintComponent(Graphics g)` é de origem da classe [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html), sendo esta herdada por todos os componentes da API swing(exceto alguns componentes [containers top-level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)), esta solução provavelmente funcionará para qualquer componente da API.

---

Baseado [nesta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35637914/5524514), é possível fazer com que a imagem seja dimensionada conforme a área exibida da tela, utilizando [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

Primeiro é necessário criar uma instancia de `BufferedImage` com  as dimensões que você deseja que a imagem seja dimensionada:

```
//dimensoes do componente do qual a imagem servirá de background
Dimension dimension = this.getSize();
int dWidth = (int)dimension.getWidth();
int dHeight = (int)dimension.getHeight();

bi = new BufferedImage(dWidth, dHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Após criar uma instância, precisamos desenhar a imagem com as dimensões informadas e, opcionalmente, definir algumas configurações pra melhorar a qualidade. O código está com as devidas explicações sobre o que cada linha faz:

```
//cria uma instância de gráficos a partir do BufferedImage
Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
//define algumas configurações de interpolação, renderização e antialiasing
//para melhorar um pouco a qualidade da imagem quando for dimensionada
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
//renderiza a imagem dentro do BufferedImage
g2.drawImage(imagem, 0, 0, dWidth, dHeight, null);
//com a imagem já desenhada, dispensa essa instância de gráficos
g2.dispose();
//desenha a imagem já dimensionada no componente
g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
```

Agora basta adicionar no método `paintComponent` do componente, não esquecendo de verificar se a imagem é válida antes de tentar desenhá-la na tela:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    BufferedImage bi;

    if (imagem != null) {

        Dimension dimension = this.getSize();
        int dWidth = (int)dimension.getWidth();
        int dHeight = (int)dimension.getHeight();

        bi = new BufferedImage(dWidth, dHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        //cria uma versao 2D de graficos para que possamos desenhar a imagem na tela
        Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
        //define algumas configurações de interpolação, renderização e antialiasing
        //para melhorar um pouco a qualidade da imagem quando for dimensionada
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        //desenha a imagem dentro do BufferedImagem
        g2.drawImage(imagem, 0, 0, dWidth, dHeight, null);
        g2.dispose();
        //finalmente, desenha a imagem já dimensionada no componente
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);

    }
}
```

Veja o resultado com uma imagem de 2560x1600 redimensionada a 300x250:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de exemplo pode ser encontrado  [neste link do github](https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples2/JDeskotpPaneBGResizingTest.java).