# Desativar botao maximizar do JFrame

Tags: java, swing

Eu configurei o tamanho para 600x600, mas queria saber como eu faço para, quando clicar no maximizar, não ficar sem o background ou até mesmo tirar o botão de maximizar e deixar apenas o de minimizar e fechar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package calculadoraimc;

import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiriT
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        TextField_Peso = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        TextField_Altura = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Peso_Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Altura_Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        TextField_Nome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Nome_Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JFundo = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Calculadora de IMC");
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Calcular");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);
        jButton1.setBounds(190, 490, 240, 60);

        TextField_Peso.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                TextField_PesoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(TextField_Peso);
        TextField_Peso.setBounds(260, 290, 180, 30);
        getContentPane().add(TextField_Altura);
        TextField_Altura.setBounds(260, 330, 180, 30);

        Peso_Label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 2, 24)); // NOI18N
        Peso_Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Peso_Label.setText("Peso");
        getContentPane().add(Peso_Label);
        Peso_Label.setBounds(170, 290, 110, 30);

        Altura_Label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 2, 24)); // NOI18N
        Altura_Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Altura_Label.setText("Altura");
        getContentPane().add(Altura_Label);
        Altura_Label.setBounds(160, 330, 110, 30);
        getContentPane().add(TextField_Nome);
        TextField_Nome.setBounds(260, 370, 180, 30);

        Nome_Label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 2, 24)); // NOI18N
        Nome_Label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        Nome_Label.setText("Nome");
        getContentPane().add(Nome_Label);
        Nome_Label.setBounds(160, 370, 110, 30);

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/calculadoraimc/ftc.png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
        jLabel2.setBounds(120, 90, 380, 150);

        JFundo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/calculadoraimc/fd.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        JFundo.setText("jLabel1");
        getContentPane().add(JFundo);
        JFundo.setBounds(0, 0, 612, 644);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String nome = TextField_Nome.getText();
    double peso = Double.parseDouble(TextField_Peso.getText());
    double altura = Double.parseDouble(TextField_Altura.getText()); 
    IMC i = new IMC(nome, peso, altura);

     TextField_Nome.setText(" ");
     TextField_Peso.setText(" ");
     TextField_Altura.setText(" ");
     i.calcularIMC();
    }                                        

    private void TextField_PesoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel Altura_Label;
    private javax.swing.JLabel JFundo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Nome_Label;
    private javax.swing.JLabel Peso_Label;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TextField_Altura;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TextField_Nome;
    private javax.swing.JTextField TextField_Peso;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, poderia reformular ?

Comment: é para que a tela não ser maximizar ou diminuir o tamanho da tela .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se não deseja que a tela seja maximizada, basta desativar o redimensionamento através do método [`setResizable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable(boolean)):

```
seuframe.setResizable(false);
```

com isso, a janela terá apenas o tamanho predefinido, não permitindo mais que seja maximizado.

Porém, é possível adaptar o fundo para que ele [redimensione junto com a tela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205296/28595), desta forma, não é necessário desativar o redimensionamento.

Lembrando que o método do link acima somente irá redimensionar o background, se quiser que os componentes do formulário acompanhem  o redimensionamento, deve usar um [**LayoutManager**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) conforme o que melhor se adequar a sua tela.

Comment: essa segunda opção é um pouco complexa para mim, vou tentar ler tudo e seguir, mas sobre esse seuframe.setResizable eu coloco o nome do meu jframe? Ex JFundo.setResizable(false); e deu um error:

Comment: @GabrielCosta não cole códigos nos comentarios por favor, pois não é o campo adequado. Você vai substituir `seuframe` pela variavel que representa seu JFrame.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ln49op o meu frame é NewJFram, mas apareceu esse error, desculpa vou apagar o comentario do codigo .

Comment: @GabrielCosta você sabe o que é uma váriavel? `NewJFrame` não é uma variável, se esse print for do mesmo código da pergunta. Esse é o nome da classe. Como a classe herda de JFrame, basta chamar o método acima dentro do construtor usando a referencia do `this`.

Comment: Se não souber o que é ou como usar o `this`, recomendo que pare um pouco sua aplicação e leia os topicos linkados, pois isso é conhecimento básico da linguagem e necessário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108960/28595 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154186/28595

Comment: Realmente, acabei me perdendo, e também não estou conseguindo achar o nome da variavel, e no caso eu chamaria dentro do construtor do NewJFrame?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, mas eu já utilizo o this a função dele eu não tenho certeza, mas eu smp utilizo para por ex: chamar uma variável que não está dentro do metodo, eu utilizo o this.

Comment: @GabrielCosta sim, o this pode ser chamado dentro do construtor, conforme  já comentei.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ln4g9q eu não tou conseguindo compreender qual desses utilizar com o setResizable.

Comment: @GabrielCosta `this.setResizable(false);` dentro do construtor.

Comment: Ahh, Sim, eu estava pensando que tinha que o nome de alguma variável, não sabia que não precisaria, eu testei sem o this, com o this, e foi normal.

Comment: @GabrielCosta funciona sem o `this` pois o compilador chama o `this` implicitamente se você não informar. Mas é essencial utilizar o this, pois há casos onde há polimorfismo de métodos herdados.

Comment: Realmente essa parte do this eu smp uso dentro de metodos, uma coisa eu estou tentando mudar uma parte do codigo dentro desse form, mas ele não permite, você sabe como eu conseguiria modificar algo manualmente?

Comment: @GabrielCosta se esse codigo foi gerado pelo netbeans, ele nao deixa mesmo.